# How can I add 'order option' when calling model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

If I add order option like this, error says

> undefined method `call' for #
>   How can I fix this?

My code in controller is

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted Community.(order: 'updated_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe you have the syntax for order wrong:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Try:

```
Community.order("updated_at DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it seemed worked perfect but order was messing. It seems ignoring order....

Comment: Have you tried visually inspecting the contents of your table? Are you sure the ordering is there?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure because I checked updated time of each record on PHPMyadmin, and it was not in the same order.